# Unable to add "Email" action within chatter component of custom object

Tags: quickaction, sales-cloud

I am unable to add Email action on custom object feed. It seems to add the action to activity timeline only. My customer wants same kind of experience as on case object where they see "Email" action on chatter feed of case object. Is this option not available for custom object?